# ¿Cómo pudo hacer el método de insertar al final?

Tags: java, netbeans

Me podrían ayudara crear el método de insertar al final es de lista enlazada simple esta es la clase de métodos si me ayudan les agradecería mucho!!!
Este es el código que llevo

```
//Método de ELIMINAR al FINAL de la lista(TAREA
public void EliminarFin() {
    if(Primero==Fin){
        Primero=Fin=null;
    }else{
        Nodo temporal=Primero;
        while(temporal.Siguiente!=Fin){
            temporal=temporal.Siguiente;
        }
        Fin=temporal;
        Fin.Siguiente=null;
    }
    size--;
}
```

Comment: Ese metodo elimina el final.. que intentaste como metodo para agregar al final?

Comment: //Método insertar en FINAL de la lista(TAREA)
    public void InsertarFin(Object valor) {
        if (Primero==null){
            Nodo nuevo=new Nodo(valor);
            Primero=nuevo;
     
        }else{
            Nodo nuevo=new Nodo(valor);
            Nodo lista=Primero;
            while(lista.Siguiente !=null){
                lista=lista.Siguiente;
            }
            lista.Siguiente=nuevo;
        }
    }

Comment: Mira [ask] para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida. También, aprovecha y haz el [tour] para entender mejor cómo funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primera [medalla](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges)! usa el boton [edit] y pone eso en la pregunta, que es justamente lo que estas preguntando.. tambien, aclara que problema tuviste...